# SDK to Read PPT , xls and .doc file in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, powerpoint

In my application i need to launch ppt , xls, pdf files. i am sure, iOS Framework support to view PDF files without launching any other application, but is there any way to open ppt , xls doc , if yes please give me any pointer,

I believe, there should be some SDKs available , which can be integrated through an application and can make use of it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you just want to view the Office files, have a look at:

- [Document Interaction Programming Topics for iOS: Quick Look Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/UsingtheQuickLookFramework.html).
- [Quick Look Framework Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/QuickLook/Reference/QuickLookFrameworkReference_iPhoneOS/_index.html)

**Quick Look Framework** supports a lot of file formats as you can see in the links above. It is available in iOS 4.0 and later.

You can also use **UIWebView** to display them. See [Using UIWebView to display select document types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2008/qa1630.html).

Comment: i show PPT file in UIWebview but its won't show any animations. how to make animation and sounds in iphone web view

Comment: `WKWebView` supersedes `UIWebView` and also supports displaying Microsoft Office files. See my [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46334049) for more details.