# Render PPT files in iOS 6

Tags: ios, ipad, uiwebview, uiimageview, powerpoint

I am developing an application where it will load Power point presentation file in UIWebView and capture the screen of the UIWebView for each page. And I am able to display as images one by one like a presentation.

Targetted platforms are: iOS6, iOS7

(1) Now when I want to display a Power Point document that has slides with multiple layered images/ elements or slides with animation
(2) Ppt files with custom size of slides

are not properly rendered by UIWebView. And hence I am seeing those slides in a different alignment and orientation. Basically not able to display as original images.

I searched in Google, Stack Overflow and even Apple documentation. Nowhere documented that this is not possible. Is there any other approach for loading ppt files where I will not lose any content or alignment?

SlideShark or Key Note are the apps which will display ppts as if original ppt slides.

Comment: You will need to parse the `PPT` file your self and display it you self. Which is not an easy task. There might be third party libraries, but request for these are off topic for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Follow App Guidelines for UIDocumentInteractionController

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/)

[Sample Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DocInteraction/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010052)

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274977/sdk-to-read-ppt-xls-and-doc-file-in-ios) will help you.
You can check file support using QLPreviewController [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/UsingtheQuickLookFramework.html).

Comment: Hi iOS Dev, thanks for your answer. Its very late to respond but.. Tried to use Quicklook framework but not helped. Still having same issue that not able to display ppt images, different page size ppts, slides with animations etc.

Comment: Were you ever able to display Powerpoint (ppt) files using existing Apple APIs?

Comment: @SteveSheets, Please check link I have provided in for QLPreviewController, it is from apple doc. it is written that you can display file iWork documents,
Microsoft Office documents (Office ‘97 and newer),
Rich Text Format (RTF) documents,
PDF files,
Images,
Text files whose uniform type identifier (UTI) conforms to the public.text  type (see Uniform Type Identifiers Reference),
Comma-separated value (csv) files.

Comment: IOS Dev, that is not what I asked. I asked if he was able to display Powerpoint files using an Apple API, not just QLPreviewController.  Since my posting, I discovered that people are displaying PowerPoint (.ppt) files using the UIWebView. That is an alternative solution from Apple.