# What File Types are Supported by WKWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview

`UIWebView` supports a whole list of file types, as detailed in [this Apple Technical Q&A doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1630/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008749):

In addition to HTML content, `UIWebView` can display specific document types.

> iPhone OS 2.2.1 supports the following document types:
>
> ```
> Excel (.xls)
> Keynote (.key.zip)
> Numbers (.numbers.zip)
> Pages (.pages.zip)
> PDF (.pdf)
> Powerpoint (.ppt)
> Word (.doc)
> ```
>
> iPhone OS 3.0 supports these additional document types:
>
> ```
> Rich Text Format (.rtf)
> Rich Text Format Directory (.rtfd.zip)
> Keynote '09 (.key)
> Numbers '09 (.numbers)
> Pages '09 (.pages)
> ```

Which is great. These days however they generally advise that developers use `WKWebView` instead of `UIWebView` as it's faster and offers significant JavaScript performance improvements. This is great, except that I can't find a list of file types that are supported.

It does appear to support media files (such as Quicktime .mov files) which `UIWebView` did not, but now Word documents (.docx) do not seem to work. **Is there a list of file formats that are supported by `WKWebView`?**

Comment: docx works for me. You can also display images (png, jp(e)g, tif).

Comment: It would be nice having a list of  mime types supported by both UIWebView or WKWebView so we could use one or the other depending on the file to display...

Comment: Have you made docx working in WKWebView?

Comment: I had weird behaviour for docx files. Works on simulator but not on device. I found that when the file is local I must use loadFileURL() whereas constructing a URLRequest and calling load() just fails quietly and doesn't display any content

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same question. I lodged a Technical Support Incident with Apple and received this answer (21st Sep 2017):

> 1. All Microsoft Documents are supported.
> 2. All iWork documents are supported.
> 3. If UIWebView would render a document type then WKWebView will as well.

On an iOS device running 10.3.3 and the Xcode 9.0 iOS 11.0 simulator, the above seems to work. I can display a range of MS Office documents (including docx, pptx, xlsx) as well as the UIWebView ones documented by Apple in [QA 1630](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1630/_index.html).

The above list is however lacking at least the various image formats, so it's clearly incomplete. If I get more information from Apple I'll update this answer...

(Bug report 17972625 requests WKWebView's documentation be updated to precisely specify what formats it does actually support, if you care to submit a duplicate to [Apple Bug Reporter](https://bugreport.apple.com/).)